# AWS CLI error redirection is not working in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm running following aws cli to check db instance in bash script. I'm getting error of An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) on terminal. I want to hide the error message.

I have redirected aws cli output. But it's not working.

Please find details below. Help me to hide the error.

```
root@ip-10-192-21-59:~/abhi# aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier test-db | grep -qi DBInstanceStatus  2>&1 >/dev/null

An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: DBInstance test-db not found.
root@ip-10-192-21-59:~/abhi#
```

Comment: Hi Ermiya, it's not working. Following command is working.. `aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier test-db 2>/dev/null | grep -qi DBInstanceStatus`

Answer (score 0):

Apply the redirection to `aws`, not `grep`.

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier test-db 2>/dev/null | grep -qi DBInstanceStatus
```

You can apply a redirection to any command(s) in a pipeline (although if you redirect `stdout` it won’t get piped to the next command).

Comment: thanks.. It's working.